# php - return header on connection_timeout

Tags: php, error-handling, header, timeout, connection

I have a shutdown function:

```
function shutdownFunction(){        
    if (connection_aborted()) {    
        header("Status: 409");
    } elseif (connection_status() == CONNECTION_TIMEOUT) {
        header("Status: 410");
    } else {
        //normal completion actions  
    } 
}
```

When the connection times out or is aborted, i would like to return a custom header status to the calling application.  Although it does execute whatever code is inside the second IF block, it still returns a 500 Internal Server Error, not the custom 409 or 410.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal Server Error is a suspension of processing PHP code, so you can not handle it with "if/else". Although exception handling with "try/catch" maybe can help.

Add: 
in .htaccess you can write this:

```
ErrorDocument 500 /error-docs/500.shtml
```

For this action you need "AllowOverride FileInfo" in your apache config file.

Comment: although i dont disagree that this sounds correct, why then does the code in the shutdown function still process if it truly suspends the PHP code from processing?

Comment: Sorry Adam, but you are really sure that the function still process? Anyway pleas see on my add to answer.

Comment: In the first and second if blocks, i put in an email function.  when the program timed out (due to manual infinite loop), i did get the email. this is the only way i could tell that it did process, because the 500 header was still returned, not the 409 or the 410.  I will look into your addition as well :)

Comment: try { /* YOUR CODE with timeout */ } catch (Exception $e) { shutdownFunction(); }

Comment: And this is maybe interesting for you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Placing the registerShutdownFunction in a try catch does execute the code, the header status is still getting the 500 =[